# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'

Tags: iphone, sdk, xcode4.3

I've got a really strange problem.. I've got my app inside a folder where i keep all my projects. If I open the app ( with Xcode 4.5 ) from that position everything is ok the app is working properly, but if I put a copy of the app on my desktop and trying to open the app to test on my iPhone this is the error is coming out ( NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model' )

I already tried to reset and clean everything is possible but nothing is not working ?

This thing drive me crazy ?

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help..

Comment: How are you accessing your `NSManagedObjectModel`?  Is the model being copied properly to the application's bundle during build?

Comment: - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"NAME" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of data base in the code line stringByAppendingPathComponent. change value from dummy.sqlite to anyOther.sqlite. This is the right solution to recreate the database.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                                           stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"dummy.sqlite"]];
NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                              initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if(![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                             configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
    /*Error for store creation should be handled in here*/
}

return persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

}

Comment: +1 for this; this was an *unexpected* solution to the following problem (in case others encounter this): I had a xcdatamodel and did 'Add Model Version..' to get a xcdatamodeld for future migration. I was getting nil error after changing URLForResource:withExtension:@"mom" to @"momd".    Running the app with [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"X.sqlite"] then changing back to @"RealModelName.sqlite" did the trick. Wish I knew why tho' as deleting the db didn't seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Found that in AppDelegate.m, I had linked the Model URL to a previous model name that was no longer in use, and hence when trying to interact with the data model, it was throwing this error.

Hope that helps anyone having the same issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

it's relatively simple.

if you have an xcdatamodel file **without** versions: use the extension "mom" in your managedObjectModel declaration.
If your xcdatamodel has versions, you should use "momd".